# How does early stopping act as a regulizer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, regularization, gradient-descent

Reading the book "Deep Learning" by Goodfellow et al., in section 7.8 (for ref. [Deep Learning - Chapter 7](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html)), I came across a demonstration of why early stopping can be interpreted as a regularization method. For a linear model the expression of the "distance" between the weights vector evaluated after $\tau$ steps and the optimal (zero gradient) weight vector $w^*$ is, under local Taylor series approximation of the loss function:
\begin{align}
w^{(\tau)} - w^*=(I-\epsilon H)(w^{(\tau-1)}-w^*),
\end{align}
where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of the loss function with respect to $w$ evaluated at $w^*$. After eigendecomposition, $H=Q\Lambda Q^T$:
\begin{align}
Q^T(w^{(\tau)}-w^*) = (I-\epsilon \Lambda)Q^T(w^{(\tau-1)} - w^*).
\end{align}
The author, then, assuming small $\epsilon: |1-\lambda_i|<1$ and initial point $w^{(0)}=0$, obtains the following identity:
\begin{align}
Q^T w^{(\tau)}=[I-(I-\epsilon\Lambda)^\tau]Q^T w^*.
\end{align}

> I tried to prove it this way, partially by "reverse engineering": with $A=I-\epsilon\Lambda$
> \begin{align}
> Q^T w^{(\tau)} &=AQ^T w^{(\tau-1)} + (I-A)Q^T w^*,\\
> Q^Tw^{(1)}&=(I-A)Q^T w^*, \text{ because $w^{(0)}=0$},\\
> Q^T w^{(2)} &=AQ^Tw^{(1)}+(I-A)Q^Tw^*\\
> &=A\color{red}{Q^T}(I-A)Q^Tw^*+(I-A)Q^Tw^*\\
> &=[A\color{red}{Q^T}(I-A)+(I-A)]Q^Tw^*\\
> &=(A\color{red}{Q^T}-A\color{red}{Q^T}A+I-A)Q^Tw^*\\
> &=[I-(A\color{red}{Q^T}A-A\color{red}{Q^T}+A)]Q^Tw^*.
> \end{align}
> How does (or should, right?) $(AQ^TA-AQ^T+A)=A^2$ given the assumptions?

**Edit**: The expression I obtained for $Q^Tw^{(2)}$ is wrong. $Q^Tw^{(1)} = (I-A)Q^Tw^*$, not $\color{red}{Q^T}(I-A)Q^Tw^*$.

I propose a continuation with a proof by induction of the proposition
\begin{align}
Q^Tw^{(\tau)}=(I-A^\tau)Q^Tw^*,
\end{align}
whose base case ($\tau=1$) has already been demonstrated.
Checking if the proposition holds for $\tau+1$, assuming it holds for $\tau$:
\begin{align}
Q^Tw^{(\tau+1)}&=AQ^Tw^{(\tau)}+(I-A)Q^Tw^*\\
&= A(I-A^\tau)Q^Tw^*+(I-A)Q^Tw^*\\
&= (I-A^{\tau+1})Q^Tw^*\\
&= [I-(I-\epsilon\Lambda)^{\tau+1}]Q^Tw^* \quad\square
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us denote for further brevity $u^{(\tau)} = Q^{\tau} w^{(\tau)}, u^{*} = Q^{\tau} w^{*}$. Then the equation connecting $\tau $ and $\tau - 1$ can be rewritten as:
$$
u^{(\tau)} = (1 - \epsilon \Lambda) u^{(\tau- 1)} + \varepsilon \Lambda u^{*}
$$
Let us suppose, that the solution has the form (the power law iteration makes this assumption natural):
$$
u^{(\tau)} = (1 - \epsilon \Lambda)^{(\tau)} x + y
$$
For some vectors $x, y$. Since $u^{(0)} = 0$ then $y = -x$.

The substitution of this ansatz gives:
$$
(1 - \epsilon \Lambda)^{\tau} x - x = (1 - \epsilon \Lambda)^{\tau} x - (1 - \epsilon \Lambda) x + \varepsilon \Lambda u^{*}
$$
Hence:
$$
x = -u^{*} \rightarrow u^{(\tau)} = (I - (1 - \epsilon \Lambda)^{\tau}) u^{*} 
$$
Returning back to the original variables $w$ we get the desired results.

Comment: How does the power law iteration make the assumed form natural and, most importantly, valid? Is it related to the fact that $\epsilon$ is small?

Comment: @caccolona no, in this form $\varepsilon$ doesn't have to be small. The only requirement is $|1 - \varepsilon \lambda_i| < 1$ for power iteration to shrink. The relation between the following 2 steps is just a [Geometric_progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) in matrix form.

Comment: Ok, so, if I correctly understood, the constraint on $\epsilon$ is only required for the optimization purpose. Anyways I found the error in my tentative proof and added an alternative to yours in the main post. Thanks